# RHEL 5 - Path Environment Variable Changes Don't Take Effect

Tags: java, linux, bash, environment-variables, rhel5

I am having a problem in Red Hat Enterprise Linux, I'm a newb to Linux so this is probably something very simple. I installed a new 64-bit JDK (1.6.0_18) on RHEL 5 (64-bit), and now i need to set the path so that linux will go for the 1.6.0_18 instead of the old JRE 1.4.2. But everytime i set the path variable, its like the changes are immediately undone.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Log in as root
2. Open Terminal, run the command: "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin"
3. Run "echo $PATH", the new path returns
4. Run "java -version", the old jre shows up.
5. Start up a new terminal, run "echo $PATH", the new path i added no longer shows up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voted to move this to [Superuser](http://superuser.com). In the meantime, take a look at the [`alternatives`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_alternatives.htm) command. It should help you with this.

Comment: @eldarerathis: RHEL -> serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I also think you should ask this in superuser or serverfault..

Try

```
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin:$PATH
```

instead, and while you are at it, this will ensure other scripts etc. would work

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18
export JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/java
```

If you want to persist these changes, try putting the above lines in `.bash_profile` or something.

The reason the above works and yours doesn't, is that the system searches from what's left in the PATH first. So if there are 2 `java` the system could use in the PATH, it will use the first one found.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to edit the .bash_profile configuration file, then reboot in order for the changes to take effect. After that everything was great! 

Btw: Ty for the suggestion to post to superuser or serverfault in the future. I've gotten used to posting my programming questions on here, forgot about those other sites.

Comment: You could just run 'source ~/.bash_profile' to reload .bash_profile, there is no need to restart. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608187/how-to-reload-bash-profile-from-the-command-line