# where all these aliases are stored?

Tags: macos, bash, iterm

On my macbook when in iterm I run

```
alias
```

I can see a bunch of aliases, huge amount are for git, and mostly they are ok, but I'd like to change some.

I tried to add few to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias gcm='git commit -m'
alias c='clear'
```

but it had no influence on the output of the `alias`.

Yes, I reloaded the iterm.

Comment: try `source ~/.bash_profile`. Now, does it work?

Comment: @John_West unfortunately not yet

Comment: What's your alias syntax?

Comment: @John_West edited the question

Comment: You can change them in your own files even if they already exist.   It depends on the order of file execution.  Start-up files are the usual place to store aliases, but the order is highly tailorable.  Look at `man bash` and search for `INVOCATION`.

Comment: @cdarke, it says `When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file  /etc/profile,  if that  file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
       exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.`

Comment: Maybe silly - does your `iterm` run `bash` by default? Check here: `iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles Tab -> General` You could have different shell.

Comment: Funny, that's what my man pages say as well.  One way to find how they are loaded is to run `bash -xl`  (that's minus ex ell).  This will give a trace of the startup files (that's the x) for a login shell (that's the ell).

Comment: However, if `source` does not work... Wrong syntax in `~/.bash_profile` somewhere above? Simply, is there a command `exit` before your aliases? :)

Comment: @John_West actually my `.bash_profile` looks suspiciously short `[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Comment: The `-s` checks if the file exists, if so (the `&&`) then "source" the file.  sourcing a file executes the commands in the current shell (otherwise it would execute it in a child process which would not affect the current one).  So obviously these aliases might be in those other files, like `.profile`.  I think `rvm` is the Ruby startup (?).

Comment: Please, edit your question with your full `.bash_profile`

Comment: The question `where` is quite simple: `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.profile` and the similar in `/etc` is the common place. See [there explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/416931). Also all scripts included (`./` or `source`) into those scripts are also executed on sessions start, your Ruby Virtual Machine `rvm` is an example. I don't understand why your custom `alias`es do not appear in `alias` list.

Comment: Oh, have you already had `gcm` and `c` aliases defined (by git, etc...)? The problem is the script running sequence then.

Comment: @John_West yea, I had `gcm` already defined, and that is my concern - I did not do so, so wanted to know, where did the come from

Comment: No, there are more places where aliases can be stored, e.g./etc/aliases, /private/etc/aliases, ~/zshrc (if zsh used) etc

Answer (score 2):

*"Where all these aliases are stored?"*

`~/.bashrc` - [this is a script invoked](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) when you start your common terminal (`iterm`, etc.) because you invoke the `non-login` shell. The difference between login and non-login sheels is beautifully explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/58326

Every script invoked from the other script can contain aliases as well.

So, I suggest you to add your aliases to the end of `~/.bashrc` if you want to overwrite the aliases created in other scripts.

You can add your custom aliases wherever you want (e.g., `als.sh`) and load them only when you want: `source als.sh`

Comment: thx a lot for a decent explanation! In the evening, when I'm at home I will test it out and get back to you, for now definitely upvote, thx again!

Comment: Not at all! Meanwhile, I fixed the answer now :) there was an error earlier

Comment: FYI since Catalina the default shell changed from Bash to ZSH, so the equivalent file is now `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

Did you log out and log in again? I think `~/.bash_profile` is the correct file, so it should work.

How to reload the bash aliases was answered before:

[How to reload .bash_profile from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608187/how-to-reload-bash-profile-from-the-command-line)

Comment: in the question I have written, that I have reloaded the iterm

Answer (score 0):

You can search whether the alias already exists using this:

```
alias | grep keyword
```

If it exists you can remove the already existing one using

```
unalias alias_name
```

Then add your new alias. done!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [oh my zsh](https://ohmyz.sh), you might have the [git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git) installed/enabled. This adds A LOT of alias' for git! Full list

One possible way to check would be to run the following, which should only give output if the git plugin is installed (assumes .zshrc file is in default `home` directory)

```
grep '^plugins.*git' ~/.zshrc
```