# How to make "g" = "git" in mac terminal?

Tags: git, macos, terminal

When I am in the terminal, if is there a way to set shortcuts for commands? For example, if I type "g" make it equal "git", and if I type "gs" make it equal "git status". etc?

Comment: To some degree, the answer depends on which shell you use.

Comment: alias or ln in some bin folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `bash` alias command.

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file (for Mac) and add the following to the end.

```
alias g="git"
alias gs="git status"
```

Changes will take any effect for any *new* terminals, but not ones that are already open.

Comment: @njha I think Nikos comment is correct. It works in bash_profile but not in .profile.

Comment: `.bash_profile` will override `.profile`. Also, it's not sourced for `sh`, only for `bash`, which makes it a good idea to put aliases in `.bash_profile` instead of `.profile` since you don't want aliases to interfere with scripts that use `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: It should be noted that changes to `~/.bash_profile` will only take effect in new terminal windows. In other words, windows that were opened before the modification won't see those aliases.

Comment: @focorner that's true. You can manually reload the profile in the current terminal session with `source ~/.bash_profile`, as detailed in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608187/how-to-reload-bash-profile-from-the-command-line

Comment: There are a lot of shells other than bash.