# Why Go is not being detected?

Tags: go

I'm trying to install Go, gRPC and Protobuf but I cant even install Go in the first place.

I followed steps mentioned in this site:

```
https://tecadmin.net/install-go-on-centos/
```

My bash_profile file looks like this now:

```
http://prntscr.com/nf2bm9
```

And when I try to test go installation by typing "go version" in the console I get this error:

```
-bash: go: command not found
```

Where did I go wrong?

Note: I navigated to /usr/local/ to see if there is any go folder with files or not to confirm the files has been downloaded and moved at the right place.

Comment: Did you relaunch your terminal for the `.bash_profile` to take effect? Are you *using* Bash? Have you done `echo $PATH` in the terminal to make sure the PATH is correct? Have you checked that `/usr/local/go/bin` exists?

Comment: Didnt knew that I had to close and open a new Terminal Window. I just did echo $PATH and it spit out this and I dont even know what Im looking at : /home/ec2-user/ec2-user/GoServerFolder/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

Comment: I dont know why it spit out "ec2-user" 2 times, because I only have 1 folder with that name.

Comment: @ceejayoz Do you think everything is fine? Am I over reacting?

Comment: Well, does `go version` work after relaunching your terminal?

Comment: Yes "go version" works.

Comment: Then it sounds like things work fine. `$PATH` tells your terminal where to look for executables, separated by `:` marks. You have several subfolders of `ec2-user`; that's fairly common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to your `.bash_profile` file only take effect after you relaunch the terminal.

[`source ~/.bash_profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608187/how-to-reload-bash-profile-from-the-command-line) will reload it in your current session, if you'd rather take that approach.