# grpcui: command not found

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am new to grpcui. I've been trying to follow the installation. I did

```
go get github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui/...
go install github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui/cmd/grpcui
```

I also added grpcui path to my `$PATH`. Even tried to pull down the repo and `make install`. But I keep getting `grpcui: command not found`. Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installation, your grpcui should be in `/home/user/go/bin`. If so, try and add that folder to your $PATH, as I did (and it worked).

Comment: Thanks mr @Adam, after reading your answer I changed directory `cd /home/user/go/bin` and I was able to run grpc command .`/grpcui -plaintext 10.129.91.206:50051`, went on my browser and I was able to get the service

Answer (score 0):

To further Adam's answer, a critical step in updating the PATH is restarting the terminal.

On OSX this needs to be done via `exec bash -l`. Simply exiting and opening the terminal does not work.

- [path gist](https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7)
- [terminal SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262349/restart-terminal-without-closing-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux system and grpcui command doesn't work even after installing the grpcui in the go/bin folder then the PATH for go is not set in the environmental variable and the go command works even without setting up the environmental varaible for it so don't get confused by it.You can always check whether PATH is set for go by using the command `echo $PATH`. If it is not set then set the PATH for go. I installed go in my home directory so you can set the path for go using the command: `export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"`. Now if you try `grpcui -help` it would be working fine.