# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins' (Cannot import create_engine)

Tags: python, cs50

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine=create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 6, in 
    engine=create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py",
line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 56, in create
    plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

And if change my code to:

[The Problem and the traceback is in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTF6W.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like `os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")` is returning `None`. Calling `create_engine(None)` give you this error. Is `DATABASE_URL` defined in your environment variable ?

Answer (score 4):

just use this as url 
"postgresql://username:password@host:port/database"
directly pass these values inside your `create_engine("postgresql://username:password@host:port/database")`

I was having the same problem now its gone.That worked for me. Only thing important to mention is that I got a different error altogether after creating the new user and database and moving the tables. The error was '

> '' ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' '''

and the solution was running: `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

PS: URL details with you details.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
   engine=create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
   db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

type this with your url:

```
   engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase")
   db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Comment: Why would you expose your connection string in your codebase?

Comment: This response does not make any sense whatsoever. If you set the environmental variable correctly, you don't need to expose your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid typing your postgresql connection (including password) in your code define your environment variable in your terminal according this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or you can use the short form of the command:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

This executes .bash_profile file in the current shell.

Additional advices concerning reloading .bash_profile can be found in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608187/how-to-reload-bash-profile-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was occurring because I hadn't put the correct path of the file I was trying to upload to my AWS db.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error because of environment variable in windows.. Environment variable of database(pinot) was not properly configured. check your variable name and key both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).