# Got AttributeError SQLsqlalchemy ('NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins')

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have problem when I try to create a database in SQLAlchemy:

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Database

```
import models

class Database:

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        engine = create_engine(db_url)
        models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
        self.maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

the error is following:

```
    plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Comment: Your object is a NoneType, which means that your are not retrieving anything. Is empty. First step should be to check your object and why you are getting an NoneType object.

Comment: Please edit your questionto include the _complete_ error traceback and the value of `db_url`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '\_instantiate\_plugins' (Cannot import create\_engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238025/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-instantiate-plugins-canno)