# How do I use flask_sqlalchemy and a GCP TLS protected DB connector?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to use flask_sqlalchemy with GCP's db connector which does automatic TLS setup as described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors#python_1

I tried their example code on my laptop with credentials set via GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and it worked. It was able to connect to the remote DB on GCP, I checked that it was TLS encrypted with wireshark, it successfully queried data from the DB. I ran that with sqlalchemy 1.4.47.

I want to use the GCP connector with a flask + flask_sqlalchemy app that uses SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. Using sqlalchemy 1.4.47 flask_sqlalcehmy 2.5.1 and code like this:

```
...

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import pg8000

...   

db: SQLAlchemy = SQLAlchemy()

def create_web_app():
    app = Flask('ex')
    ...

    ip_type = IPTypes.PUBLIC
    connector = Connector()

    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
            app.config["GCPTSLPROTECTED_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"],
            "pg8000",
            user=app.config["GCPTSLPROTECTED_DB_USER"],
            password=app.config["GCPTSLPROTECTED_DB_PASS"],
            db=app.config["GCPTSLPROTECTED_DB_NAME"],
            ip_type=ip_type,
        )
        return conn

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_BINDS"] = {
          "gcptslprotected": {
             # This URI looks funny but is what GCP docs request and works in the test script
             "url": make_url("postgresql+pg8000://"), 
             "creator": getconn }
    }

    ...
    # SQLALCHEMY_URI for a default db connection also gets created and works fine
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_URI'] = "sqlite:///./tests/data/test.db"
    
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
```

The above code runs fine but then a route in the flask app uses the DB this this error is raised:

```
File "/home/bdc34/.pyenv/versions/browse310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 516, in create_engine
u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

You might notice that I use make_url() where as the GCP example script does not have that. I did that to get around an exception raised by flask_sqlalchemy function `apply_driver_hacks()` which is not the most confidence inspiring name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '\_instantiate\_plugins' (Cannot import create\_engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238025/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-instantiate-plugins-canno)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that flask_sqlalchemy says in the docs that it will passe the dict in the `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` to sqlalchemy `creat_engine()` but it does not seem to correctly do this.

So I looked for a place in flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy to override something to make it work and I found that `set_options` calls `apply_driver_hacks` and that was an okay place.

I did:

```
class BrowseSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    """Overrides how flask_sqlalchemy handles options 
    that need to be passed to create_engine.

    In spite of documentation to the contrary, flask_sqlalchemy 
    does not seem to be able to handle a dict as the value for a 
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS.
    """

    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, sa_url, options): # type: ignore
        if not isinstance(sa_url, dict):
            return super().apply_driver_hacks(app, sa_url, options)

        url = make_url(sa_url["url"])
        options.update(sa_url)
        options.pop("url")
        return url, options

 db: SQLAlchemy = BrowseSQLAlchemy()
```

I came to these conclusions after looking at the flask_sqlalchemy code. It can be deduced that `get_options()` and `apply_driver_hasks()` are not intended to accept a Dict for the `sa_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replicate your issue. What I did to resolve it is by following this quickstart on [connecting to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-cloud-shell). Please be advised that there are other steps on connecting from other services (private IP, Cloud SQL Auth Proxy, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, etc.) which can be found on the left pane.

Below are some steps you need to check to connect to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL:

- Run `gcloud services enable sqladmin.googleapis.com` command using Cloud Shell to enable the APIs required for this quickstart.
- Make sure that the Postgre instance details (`instance_connection_name`, `db_user`, `db_pass`, `db_name`) are correct.
- Make sure to install `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install required dependencies. You can check for additional steps through this [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/b4bd938d759bd4aa2b46fc838e14eaa19d90dbf7).
- Since I deployed it using Cloud Shell, I used `gcloud sql connect [myinstance] --user=postgres`. This prompted me for the password of my instance.

This what appeared when connected to Cloud Shell:

```
Allowlisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.                                                                                                        
Connecting to database with SQL user [db_user].Password: 
psql (15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg110+1), server 14.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

[image: 3]

For some strange reason, I've repeated this step like 9-10 times as I encountered different errors when I deployed my project.

You can also [file a bug](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in case the aforementioned steps didn't work out or [contact Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for additional assistance with regards to your concern.